# Button not being enabled

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a few buttons which look like this, the other three are exactly the same but with different text and ID.

```
<p id="a"> Counters on A: 0 </p> <button onclick="add('a')" disabled>Add</button>
```

I initially have the buttons disabled, but would like to enable them after button X1 is clicked. At the end of the function that is called when X1 is clicked I add the following lines

```
document.getElementById("a").disabled = false;
```

For some reason the buttons are still disabled. And I did a few tests and the program reaches before and after the enabling of the method but that one line is not being enabled. Why is this?

Comment: You are getting the element <p> by id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<p> Counters on A: 0 </p> <button onclick="add('a')" disabled id="a">Add</button>

document.getElementById("a").disabled = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

You assigned an id "a" to the < p > element, not the button.